# Script doesn't wait for onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, why does the header text change on page load, and not only after the button is clicked?

```
<h1 id="header">This is a header</h1>
<button id="btn1">Change text</button>
<script>
  function change_text(target_id, target_text) {
    document.getElementById(target_id).textContent = target_text;
}

button1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
button1.onclick = change_text("header", "something")
</script>
```

Comment: You are setting the onclick to a function execution not a function definition. So when the onclick is defined it will execute the function. So you would want something more like:

button1.onclick = function() { change_text("header", "something"); }

Comment: Because you're setting your onclick to the function, which runs the function. This isn't how you would perform this task.

Comment: Another duplicate, specific to event handlers: [Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7102413)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
button1.onclick = change_text("header", "something")
```

The JS engine will do the following in this order:

1. Call `change_text` with the arguments `"header"` and `"something"`
2. Assign the result of `change_text` (in this case, `undefined`) to `button1.onclick`

[Jane Doe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181185/211627) should work. If you want to keep your current code structure, then you could use the following:

```
button1.onclick = function(){
    change_text("header", "something");
};
```

This creates an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and assigns it to `onclick`. When `onclick` is triggered, it will execute the function which calls `change_text`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to reuse that function and keep the onclick out of the markup, you could do this:

```html
<h1 id="header">This is a header</h1>
<button id="btn1">Change text</button>
<script>
function change_text(target_id, target_text) {
    document.getElementById(target_id).textContent = target_text;
}

button1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
button1.onclick = function () {
    change_text("header", "something");
}
</script>
```

This uses something called an `anonymous function`.

Learn more here: [JavaScript Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
<h1 id="header">This is a header</h1>
<button onclick="change_text('header', 'something')" id="btn1">Change text</button>
<script>
  function change_text(target_id, target_text) {
    document.getElementById(target_id).textContent = target_text;
}
</script>
```

I am pretty confident that will work as intended for you..

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: you have already called `change_text("header", "something")` in your code. You are basically doing the same thing as:

```
let res = change_text("header", "something") // already called, res is undefined
button1.onclick = res
```

If you are actually passing an event handler, it should looks like `button1.onclick = change_text`, with `change_text()` taking an `event` as param instead. OR as seen in the other answer, `<button onclick="change_text('header', 'something')" id="btn1">Change text</button>` (this creates an anonymous function that would be called on click event)